# Probability solution doubts

Tags: probability

I have a doubt on an exercise and this is the request:

A family would have 5 children, what is the probability to have all the children female (so 5 female children) OR all the children male (so 5 male children)? 
Probability female = 0.55

Probability male= 0.45

Any help is apprecited.

Thank you

Comment: What is your doubt? What is in your thinking e.g. the probability that all children are male? Please make this clear by means of an edit of your question (not a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: What is the probability that the desired outcome happens once? Twice? etc.

This problem is an application of [repeated events](https://www.quora.com/If-the-probability-of-an-event-occurring-is-0-04-and-you-repeat-the-same-action-250-times-what-is-the-probability-of-that-event-NOT-occurring).

Comment: ok this my idea... explain better.. all female are $0.55^5$ and all male are $0.45^5$ now, how can I calc that are or 5 female or 5 male? this is my doubt

Comment: @BigBoy The word "or" implies summation

Comment: Perfect, this is the explanation that I sarch... so: $0.55^5 + 0,45^4 = 6.88 \% $ right?

Comment: @BigBoy The answer I got was .069. Probability can never be greater than 1

Comment: "*The word 'or' implies summation*"  This needs to have a warning attached to it.  Sure, the probability of event $A$ or event $B$ happening is $Pr(A\cup B) = Pr(A)+Pr(B)$ when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint mutually exclusive events with no possibility of occurring together, such as here.  In more general settings though, it is slightly more complicated.  In general you actually have $Pr(A\cup B) = Pr(A)+Pr(B)\color{red}{-Pr(A\cap B)}$.  When flipping two coins, the probability of flipping a head on the first coin or a head on the second is not $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$ but rather $\frac{3}{4}$

Comment: @FoiledIt24 note the percentage sign. @ BigBoy, you did nothing wrong multiplying by $100\%$.  Foiled just didn't read your answer correctly.

Comment: @JMoravitz a question... two different coins are disjoint events or not?

Comment: @BigBoy do not confuse *disjoint* with *independent*.  These mean different things.  No, the event that the first coin shows heads is not disjoint from the event that the second coin shows heads.  These can both happen at the same time.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes is right! independent but not disjoint... instead a new born is or female or male and not both and is disjoint and independet... Maybe a twin birth is similar to the flipping of two coins because we can have for example male/female or male/male and female/female... I hope to have explained good

Comment: The event that Child1 being born male is disjoint from the event that Child1 is born female.  The event that Child1 being born male is *not independent* from the event Child1 being born female.  The event that Child1 being born male is *not disjoint* from the event Child2 being born male.  The event Child1 being born male is independent (*presumably*) from the event Child2 being born male.  This is getting rather off topic, but unless one of the events occurs with probability zero you will never have two events simultaneously be both disjoint and independent.

Comment: @JMoravitz I was aware of the general rule but given the context of the OP's problem I knew it was not needed here. It is still good to know it for future exercises